# Design pattern that can take either obj-X or obj-Y and turns either of those into obj-Z C#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I've been sitting with this for quite some time, trying to figure out which design pattern to use, or whether it even fits into any of the design patterns.
I have 3 objects.
Object X
Object Y
Object Z
Object X and Object Y have some similarities in them. I have the need to transform these, 1 at a time into another object, being Object Z.
But i can't figure out which way is best to do this. I have to use a design pattern to do this.
I've looked into factory, abstract factory, prototype and builder. While all of these seems to be able to work, it just seems really forced.
Hopefully it makes sense what i'm trying to do..
Does anyone now an approach to to it ?

To simplify it with pseudo
code it's something like this

```
new ObjectX(Customer) { name = "bob", age = 22, spent = 3200, vip = false}

new ObjectY(Employee) { name = Frigg, age = 24, jobTitle = developer, monthlyPay = 4000}


new ObjectZ(people) { name = ObjectX.name, age = ObjectX.age}
new ObjectZ(people) { name = ObjectY.name, age = ObjectY.age}
```

Comment: Could you provide some example code? Making X and Y act as Z kinda sounds like the Adapter Pattern - especially if the resulting object implements Z as an interface or inherits from Z

Comment: I've added some pseudo code to the question

Comment: Is your goal to do without making any changes to X or Y (such as having them implement a common interface)?

Comment: How about Inheritance? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/inheritance#:~:text=C%23%20and%20.NET%20support%20single%20inheritance%20only.%20That,which%20inherits%20from%20the%20base%20class%20type%20A.

Comment: Yes i don't need to make changes to X and Y. I just need to take values from them to create the new object Z

Comment: Assuming you can modify `X` and `Y` then inheritance or interface implementation is pretty straight forward. An example implementing a common interface ( https://dotnetfiddle.net/O3yDqt )

Answer (score 1):

You can just use inheritance for this. No transformation is necessary, any of your code that accepts Person will also accept Employee or Customer. Please see [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hn4bBt) based on your sudo code.